# Getting the same day across different years in R

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation, lubridate, smoothing

I have a dataset for a time series spanning a couple of years with daily observations. I'm trying to smooth some clearly wrong data inserted there (for example, negative values when the variable cannot take values below zero) and what I came up with was trying to smooth it or "interpolate" it by using both the mean of the days around that observation and the mean of the same day or couple of days from previous years, as I have yearly seasonality (I'm still unsure about this part, any comment would be greatly appreciated).

So my question is whether I can easily access the same day acrosss different years.

Here's a dummy example of my data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

              date      value
2016-10-01 00:00:00     28  
2016-10-02 00:00:00     25    
2016-10-03 00:00:00     24   
2016-10-04 00:00:00     22     
2016-10-05 00:00:00     -6    
2016-10-06 00:00:00     26
```

I have that for years 2016 through 2020. So in this example I would use the dates around 2016-10-05  AND I would like to use the dates around the 5th of October from years 2017 to 2020 to kind of maintain the seasonality, but maybe this is incorrect.

I tried to use `+years()` from `lubridate` but I still have to do things manually and I would like to kind of autimatize things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is solely "whether [you] can easily access the same day [across] different years", you could do that as follows:

```
# say your data frame is called df
library(lubridate)
day(df$date)
```

This will return the day part of the date for every entry in that column of your data frame.

Edit to reply to comment from asker:

This is a very basic way to specify the day and month for which you would like to obtain the corresponding rows in your data frame:

```
df[day(df$dates) == 5 & month(df$dates) == 10, ]
```

Comment: But that only gives me the day and I want day+month so I can get all October 5th's rows for example.

Comment: Answer edited to include an example of specifying which month and day you would like to obtain rows for.

Comment: Thank you! In order to do it without inserting the numbers manually I guess I could use something like `day(df$dates) == day(df$dates[index])` where ìndex` has the index(es) where the wrong data is stored, right? Is there a more straight-forward way of doing this?

Comment: Is `index` another column in your data frame?

`day(df$dates[index])` wouldn't actually work as you would be asking for the `day` of the object `df$dates[index]` which won't exist based on what you included above.

Comment: I would create ir as a new column or variable -I don't mind either of those options-, when looking for these wrong observations. So for instance in the question's example `index` would be either an array with value `5` or a new logical column like `FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE`

Comment: I don't follow; is this new `index` column/variable related to the fact that on October 5th there are negative numbers in the `value` column of your data frame? Would you like to extract all rows that contain a negative number in the `value` column?

Comment: Yes, I would first look for bad data like the October 5th one in the example. That would give me the rows where this is happening and that's what `index` would return. Then I would use it to get the days around the wrong data.

Comment: So, if you would like to find all days in your dataset that contain a negative number in the `value` column, you can do: `bad_dates = df[df$value < 0, "date"]`. Then you can access the day and month of these bad dates as before with the `day` and `month` functions and you can use those in your data frame subsetting.